# Im trying to use xcrun altool to get my app notarised, what is --asc-provider parameter?

Tags: xcode, notarization

I'm trying to notarise my app from apple using xcrun altool, the documentation shows the following :

xcrun altool --notarize-app
--primary-bundle-id "com.example.ote.zip"
--username "AC_USERNAME"
--password "@keychain:AC_PASSWORD"
--asc-provider <ProviderShortname>
--file OvernightTextEditor_11.6.8.zip

but I couldn't find the parameter to provide to the --asc-provider can any one let me know what it is and where to search for that parameter. All other parameters I have found and fine. Help me out I'm new to mac.

Comment: Are you asking if that is a required field? Drop it and rerun or edit in a specific error response if you face a non-documentation issue with this. There’s a good read the friendly man page answer since you didn’t show any research in the question. (No judgement, just [ask] if you want a follow on question when you have a specific error to solve.

Comment: hi, see I'm new to mac and the man page shows that you have to provider when there are more than one provider and that i have already found out. but I need to know what is this provider. from where can i get the information on provider, I don't need help on notarization since  man pages describes that. but I dont know what to give for the --asc-provider argument pls help on that. where can i get the provider shortname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `altool` manual page

The manual for `altool` can be viewed by running the command `man altool`. The manual states:

> `--asc-provider provider_shortname`
>
> Required with `--notarize-app` and `--notarization-history` when a user account is associated with multiple providers.

Without your knowing, it is unlikely that your account is associated with multiple providers.

### asc-provider

If you believe you need a provider, see Apple's [Customizing the Notarization Workflow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow):

> You can omit the asc-provider option for the notarization call if your credentials are associated with only a single team. Otherwise, use the option to indicate the provider short name for the appropriate team. Starting in Xcode 11, you can use `altool` to get a table of providers, provider short names, and team IDs associated with a given username and password using the list-providers option:
>
> ```
> xcrun altool --list-providers -u "AC_USERNAME" -p "@keychain:AC_PASSWORD"
> ```

Comment: I don't know my provider name, It shows that my account is associated with multiple providers. Please let me know where can i get the provider information?

Comment: I have extended the answer showing how to obtain the account's provider list.

Answer (score 3):

The provider is nothing but the membership account that you use. This is apple developer account.

In the developer account there can be different membership account inside that and that account is the provider for the certificates or profiles or identifiers you create

Provider short name can be known from the membership account page for reference see the image below

[image]

Comment: I have searched a lot to know what is called the provider. after trying the command <xcrun altool --list-providers -u "AC_USERNAME" -p "@keychain:AC_PASSWORD">, I came to know that the provider short name is nothing but the apple Team ID

Comment: This solution was also helpful for me. I can find a 10-letter ID consists of upper case letters and numbers. The short-name can be also find on the Common Name of Developer ID certificates.